# How to fill ttk.button with yellow in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout

I made a button like below using tk.Button

```
self.rule_button = tk.Button(self.Canvas1, compound=tk.CENTER, bg= 'yellow', font=('Helvetica', 25, 'bold'),text="4 person")
self.button1_window = self.Canvas1.create_window(self.screenwidth/5 * 4,self.screenheight/5 * 3, window=self.rule_button)
```

I made a button like below using ttk.Button

```
self.style = ttk.Style()

self.style.map("C.TButton", 
            foreground=[('pressed', 'red'), ('active', 'blue')],
            background=[('pressed', '!disabled', 'yellow'), ('active', 'yellow'),  ['!active', 'yellow']],)

self.style.configure("C.TButton", width = 6, font=('Helvetica', 25, 'bold'), padding = 10)

self.rule_button = ttk.Button(self.Canvas1, compound=tk.CENTER, 
                text="4 person", style="C.TButton")
```

But the button is not filled with yellow like in tk.button.

How do I configure it when using ttk?

Comment: You cannot change the button background using default theme.  Try using another theme.

Comment: Try some other theme like clam, alt, winative,etc,

Answer (score 1):

To me the buttons look the same, but maybe I miss something.

I've made an example, I'm on Debian.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_exit)
        #self.geometry("400x300")
        self.title("Simple App")

        self.style = ttk.Style()

        #...but...the bg colour it's ever yellow?
        self.style.map("C.TButton",
                       foreground=[('pressed', 'red'), ('active', 'blue')],
                       background=[('pressed', '!disabled', 'yellow'), ('active', 'yellow'),  ['!active', 'yellow']],)

        self.style.configure("C.TButton", width = 6, font=('Helvetica', 25, 'bold'), padding = 10)

        
        self.init_ui()
       
    def init_ui(self):

        f = ttk.Frame(padding = 8)

        self.rule_button = tk.Button(f, compound=tk.CENTER, bg= 'yellow', font=('Helvetica', 25, 'bold'),text="4 person")

        self.rule_button.pack(fill=tk.X, expand=1)

        self.styled_rule_button = ttk.Button(f, compound=tk.CENTER,  text="4 person", style="C.TButton")
        self.styled_rule_button.pack(fill=tk.X, expand=1)
        
        f.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)        
            
    def on_exit(self):
        if messagebox.askokcancel(self.title(), "Do you want to quit?", parent=self):
            self.destroy()               
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

[image]